# Token management with aws cognito and nextjs13 app router microservice

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, next.js13

I have the following setup for a web application:

- Nextjs13 App router which has a login page, sign up page and a page to show results fetched from dynamo db.
- A python(boto3) microservice backend for login/signup and the dynamodb fetch api. the dynamodb fetch api is protected by the cognito user pool.

How to token manage here for the subsequent secure requests?

how to store the token I get from login and send that with the dynamodb request?

localstorage is not an option because that requires client side execution which is not possible in middleware and I want the site to be rendered.

cookies is an option but obviously not that secure.